# Eliminar una rama Git tanto el local como en remoto

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-fork

> Pregunta original: [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely) [de Matthew Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95592/matthew-rankin)

Quiero eliminar una rama tanto en local como en la bifurcación de mi proyecto remoto en Github.

Eliminado rama local con éxito

```
$ git branch -D bugfix
Deleted branch bugfix (was 2a14ef7).
```

Nota: La opción `-D` es un atajo de `--delete --force`. Si quieres eliminar la rama local que debe ser totalmente fusionado en las ramas superiores, utiliza `-d` que es un atajo de `-delete`.

Intentos fallidos de eliminar una bifurcación remota

```
$ git branch -d remotes/origin/bugfix
error: branch 'remotes/origin/bugfix' not found.

$ git branch -d origin/bugfix
error: branch 'origin/bugfix' not found.

$ git branch -rd origin/bugfix
Deleted remote branch origin/bugfix (was 2a14ef7).

$ git push
Everything up-to-date

$ git pull
From github.com:gituser/gitproject
* [new branch] bugfix -> origin/bugfix
Already up-to-date.
```

¿Que necesito hacer de forma diferente para eliminar con éxito la rama remotes/origin/bugfix tanto local como en Github?

Comment: considero que esta pregunta debe ser cerrada así como marcada como Wiki según los lineamientos de la comunidad , pero no se puede reportar poque adicionalmente tiene asignada una recompensa... recompensa por copiar una respuesta ...

Answer (score 12):

> Respuesta original: [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/2003515#2003515)
>   [de Matthew Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95592/matthew-rankin)

**Respuesta actualizada en 1-Feb-2012**

A partir de [Git v1.7.0](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.0.txt), puedes eliminar una rama remota utilizando:

```
git push origin --delete <NombreRama>
```

que es más fácil de recordar que

```
git push origin :<NombreRama>
```

que fue añadido en [Git v1.5.0](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.0.txt)  “para eliminar una rama remota o una etiqueta”.

Por consiguiente, la versión de git que has instalado impondrá si necesitas utilizar la sintaxis más fácil o la más difícil.

**Respuesta original de 5-Jan-2010**

Del capítulo 3 de [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) de Scott Chacon:

> **Eliminar ramas remotas**
>
> Supón que has terminado una rama remota – tu y tus colaboradores han
>   finalizado con una caracteristica y lo habeis fusionado en vuestras
>   ramas maestras remotas (o cualquier rama en el que tu código estable
>   este). Puedes eliminar una rama remota utilizando en vez de la
>   sintaxis obtusa `git push [NombreRemoto] :[Rama]`. Si quieres eliminar
>   tu la rama serverfix del servidor, haz lo siguiente:
>
> ```
>     $ git push origin :serverfix 
>     To git@github.com:schacon/simplegit.git
>       - [deleted]         serverfix
> ```
>
> Ya no tienes la rama en tu servidor.
>
> Como hay un gran posibilidad que se te olvide la sintaxis, podrías
>   querer recordar este comando más tarde. Una forma de recordar este
>   comando es llamando a la sintaxis `git push [NombreRemoto][RamaLocal]:[RamaRemota]` que mencionamos antes. Si no pones la parte
>   `[localbranch]`, entonces estas diciendo basicamente, “ No tomar nada en
>   mi parte y hazlo `[remotebranch]` ”.

Yo utilicé `git push origin :bugfix` y funcionó muy bien. Scott Chacon estaba en lo cierto – Yo pondría en favoritos esa página (o hacerlo aquí, respondiendo en Stack Overflow).

Comment: Amigo, es interesante lo que traduces, pero tus auto-respuestas (al ser traducida y auto-respondida al instante) deben ser wikis, te recomiendo que te leas: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl

Comment: Las traducciones son aceptables y es aceptable recibir reputación por ellas como se puede leer en este mensaje del community manager : http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/93/301

Comment: Hola Carlos, de eso mismo hablé con Nestor Soriano y le comenté que cambiará a wiki mis traduciones y me respondió por email esto:

Comment: JuanM y yo, como moderadores, podemos hacer y deshacer wikis con un
clic. Pero ese no es el camino.

Sí que es verdad que hay gente que opina que todas las traducciones
deberían ser wikis, pero eso desvirtúa el significado original del
concepto. Wiki significa "esta publicación se puede beneficiar de
múltiples ediciones por parte de (casi) cualquiera a lo largo del
tiempo", no "no mereces esta reputación".

Comment: Tengo pendiente escribir una pregunta FAQ en Meta con una explicación
al respecto. De momento, no es necesario que te preocupes más por el
tema. Simplemente pregunta, responde, comenta y ayúdanos a construir
una gran comunidad para un gran sitio. :-)

Comment: Entonces no se que pensáis, yo solo quiero generar contenido, pero el tema de la reputación no es mi objetivo.

Comment: No me parece mal traducir cosas del inglés para responder, pero me parece que no tiene sentido copiar por copiar, si nadie lo preguntó en español no tiene sentido responderlo "por las dudas". Además me parece que al ser preguntas traducidas van a ser más difíciles de encontrar por personas de habla hispana que tengan la duda.

Comment: @GuilhermeBussiDias yo mismo me encuentro buscando en google esta misma pregunta casi todos los días, así que pasadas 24 horas le otorgaré +50 de reputación a tu respuesta. Muchas gracias por tu aportación y espero que sigas animado a generar contenido, tanto original como traducido.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -d -mi-rama
```

This command delete local branch. If you want to delete a remote branch, you need to use `git push origin :branchInOrigin`.

este comando elimina la rama localmente pero no en remoto, la manera mas sencilla de eliminarla de origin es poniendo.

```
git push origin :mi-rama
```