# Dejar de hacer seguimiento a branch remota

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Hola comunidad estoy teniendo un inconveniente con git que no he podido solucionar, sucede que luego de hacer el git clone de un repositorio, tuve que crear una rama local y una remota con el mismo nombre. En mi local apliqué el siguiente comando git branch nombreramalocal origin/nombrederamaremota y se inició el seguimiento a la rama remota, el caso es que quiero dejar de hacer seguimiento a esa rama remota.

Ya he eliminado la rama y cuando la vuelvo a crear aun me sigue haciendo el seguimiento.
Agradezco su atención.

Comment: Fijate si esto no responde a tu pregunta: [Eliminar una rama Git tanto el local como en remoto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1740/eliminar-una-rama-git-tanto-el-local-como-en-remoto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar esto:

```
git checkout ramalocal
git branch --unset-upstream
```

Con esto se debería eliminar la relación en el repo local.